# Get mangled name of function when using .so shared library from Android c++ side? (libAudioFlinger.so)

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries

i have been working on this problem for 2 weeks now, i have integrate C++ code into my Voip call recording app, the code is supposed to take care of forcefully setting Input_source of mediaRecorder to same one as from the Voip Call (in my case it is input_source=7 / Voice_Communication).
In order to achieve my goal i load shared library : libaudioflinger.so and attempt to reach SetParameters function, as can be seen from the snipet below :

```
handleLibAudioFlinger = dlopen("libaudioflinger.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

    if (handleLibAudioFlinger != NULL) {
        func = dlsym(handleLibAudioFlinger, "setParameters"); // i do not know the mangled name of 
                                                                 SetParameters function
        if (func != NULL) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", "Function is not null");
            result = 0;
        }
        audioSetParameters = (lasp) func;
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", "Function is null");
        result = -1;
    }
```

dlopen does not return null, but dlsym does, reason is that i need to have the exact mangled name of the function setParameters from AudioFlinger.cpp [As in Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/49dd5cf3469cd755321f8ec10013ad4fcfaf723d/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp).

i am new to handling android c++ code and dealing with shared libraries,etc... if someone can tell me step by step how to get correct mangled name for the function that i need?

Comment: Can't you pull the .so file from the device and run something like `strings libaudioflinger.so | grep setParameters` ? Note that if you're going to rely on details like the mangled name, you should probably bundle a specific version of libaudioflinger.so with your app.

Comment: Do you use rooted device? Because "libaudioflinger.so is not accessible from NDK it is AOSP system library.

Comment: basically i am trying to immitate CallrecorderFix.c provided by CallRecLib as you can see from following link : https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib/blob/master/library/src/main/cpp/callrecfix.c                                                                                                                                   in there they reference a library in LIbmedia.so with its mangled name, i do not know why but their apporaches works on all android <= 7, so i am trying to immitate that and refrence SetParameters from libAudioFlinger.so

Comment: I understand what you want to do, my concern was about your device is it rooted or not, because if your app is not system app you can not even be able to call ```dlopen("libaudioflinger.so")``` successfully, but if you wrote that it returned not NULL it seems that it is rooted.

Comment: i understand, this approach was supposed to be for rooted and non-rooted devices, as the CallRecLib specifies a solution that does not need root, my phone is rooted but i want this to work on non-rooted also, how should i go from here? include libaudioflinger in the project as a .so file? if so how may i get it, i mean from where can i download it? or i need to complie AOSP?  and the mangled  function name persists....